# Trying to access v-if condition in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

**I have written this v-if condition inside a html template. And here i want to write this condition inside a javascript because I have many templates where I am using same condition in html so due to that I am facing some performance issue**

```
 <div v-if="(category == 'Real Estate | Single Family Homes')||(category == 'Real Estate | Town Homes')||(category == 'Real Estate | Condominiums')||(category == 'Real Estate | Multi Family')||(category == 'Real Estate | Mobile Homes')||(category == 'Real Estate | Farm/Ranch Land')||(category == 'Real Estate | Commercial Property')||(category == 'Real Estate | Foreclosures')||(category == 'Real Estate | Storage')||(category == 'Real Estate | Vacation Property')||(category == 'Real Estate | Open Houses')||(category == 'Real Estate | Other Properties')">
               
<vue-form-g :schema="schema_Real_Estate" :model="model" :options="formOptions"></vue-form-g>

<span class="prev_next">
<button class="prev_next_btn" @click.prevent="prev()">Previous</button>
<button style="background-color:lightgray;" class="prev_next_btn" @click.prevent="next(2)">Next</button>
</span>
</div>
```

**Here I have tried to access inside a javscript and written that condition in this way after I have accessed this in template by using "v-if="condition" but this is not affecting in my template and also I am facing an error like "category is not define". So how to solve this issue please help me**

```
<script>
    get condition(){
    return [
        'Real Estate | Single Family Homes',
        'Real Estate | Town Homes',
        'Real Estate | Condominiums',
        'Real Estate | Multi Family',
        'Real Estate | Mobile Homes',
        'Real Estate | Farm/Ranch Land',
        'Real Estate | Commercial Property',
        'Real Estate | Foreclosures',
        'Real Estate | Storage',
        'Real Estate | Vacation Property',
        'Real Estate | Open Houses',
        'Real Estate | Other Properties',
    ].includes('category')
},
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think there are two things going wrong here. First, it looks like you can't actually access **category** inside of your current condition. Second, I don't think your condition is set up right. It also looks like you're using Vue 3, so what about something like this below? It uses a [computed property](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#basic-example) and Vue 3.

```
<template>
  <div v-if="containsCategory"></div>
</template>

<script>
  data(){
    return {
      availableCategories: [
        'Real Estate | Single Family Homes',
        'Real Estate | Town Homes',
        'Real Estate | Condominiums',
        'Real Estate | Multi Family',
        'Real Estate | Mobile Homes',
        'Real Estate | Farm/Ranch Land',
        'Real Estate | Commercial Property',
        'Real Estate | Foreclosures',
        'Real Estate | Storage',
        'Real Estate | Vacation Property',
        'Real Estate | Open Houses',
        'Real Estate | Other Properties',
      ],
      // category key/value pair goes here somewhere
    }
  },
  computed() {
    containsCategory() {
      return this.availableCategories.includes(this.category)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Otter. This solution has helped me a lot.